# Working with the PDB file

Tags: c#, pdb-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use PDB files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72104/how-do-i-use-pdb-files)

I was just about to release a new version of an application when I realised there was a pdb file. I found some good information about what it does, helping with the debugging when running live. 
But how do I work with it later? 
If the customer returns and ask why an application keeps crashing, how can I use the pdb file to find what happened?

Any tips is helpful.

Comment: @Zach, I would agree, I thought I had scouted stack for the information but obviously not, thanks for the link!