# Go To Definition of method call in Refrenced dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have two projects A is of type webservice and B is of type class library project. Project A refrences B.dll. In A when I right click some method and click Go to defenition,if it is defined in project B,it should open the source of project B.I have B.pdb already added to project A. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the source code of B.dll included to your project?

Unless you have the source code of that library, you cannot view the source code. However, you can see the `definitions` like in the same way as you can view the definitions of `FCL`.

**About PDB:** PDB files map an assembly's MSIL to the original source lines. This means that if you put the PDB that was compiled with the assembly in the same directory as the assembly, your exception stack traces will have the names and lines of the positions in the original source files. Without the PDB file, you will only see the name of the class and method for each level of the stack trace.

I took the definition from [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72104/how-do-i-use-pdb-files). Said by [Omer van Kloeten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4979/omer-van-kloeten).

Comment: I have the source code of B.dll as a seperate project. Any way I can link these two to achieve my target?

Comment: Yes, On Solution Explorer -> right click to the solution file -> Add-> Existing Project. Now browse your project to add. Once you added the project B, right click on project A->Add References-> Go to Project Tab & select the project B. Done!