# Compiled files in VS

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, deployment

When I compile a project in VB i get the following files:

```
<ProjectName>.exe
<ProjectName>.exe.config
<ProjectName>.pdb
<ProjectName>.vshost.exe
<ProjectName>.vshost.exe.config
<ProjectName>.vshost.exe.manifest
```

A quick search of them all gives info about them holding information of debugdata and such. But how do they help me? Do you guys ever use these files?

Let's say I'll make a program and send it away to a friend, what is recommended to send? Just the .exe file or something more?

Comment: `.exe` and `.exe.config` are all that's necessary to deploy (plus any referenced DLLs).  If you build in Release mode the other files should go away.  The rest are used by Visual Studio when debugging.

Comment: Depends on whether you want them to edit the source or if you just want them to use the software. As a slight aside, I'm not sure how on topic this is for here, so this question may be closed.

Comment: PDB: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202083/whats-the-pdb-file/

Comment: VSHost files: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774187/what-is-the-purpose-of-vshost-exe-file

Comment: Why are people downvoting? What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project output (here the exe, but could be a DLL if the project type is a library for exemple) and the config files are needed to use the program, plus any dependency you could use in your project (external libraries for example)

The pdb and vshost files are used by your programs for debug, not directly by yourself. And they are only generated in the debug configuration (edit: can also be generated in release, depending on your configuration).

More SO questions about those files: see ClickRick links in comments & other links:

About PDB:

- [What's the PDB file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202083/whats-the-pdb-file/)
- [How do I use PDB files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72104/how-do-i-use-pdb-files?lq=1)

About VSHOST files:

- [What is the purpose of the vshost.exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774187/what-is-the-purpose-of-vshost-exe-file)
- http://geekswithblogs.net/pavelka/archive/2006/08/11/WhatIsTheVshostExeDoing.aspx

Comment: In fact all answers are providing a part of the global answer.

Comment: Yeah, I saw. But I can only accept one I'm afraid. Is that why people were downvoting it?

Comment: I don't know, maybe the downvotes are because it's not a real 'development' question

Comment: @DavidLarsson people are down voting your question because with only a few clicks you could find the same questions (tons of them) already answered.

Comment: @NicolasR Yeah, I guess. To me this is just as much development as the actual coding - but yeah. I see your point. Anyway, thanks for your time. It is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything explained here:

[What is the purpose of the vshost.exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774187/what-is-the-purpose-of-vshost-exe-file)

To quote Daniel Brückner:

> .exe - the 'normal' executable
>
> .vshost.exe - a special version of the executable to aid debuging; see
>   [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1%28vs.71%29.aspx) for details
>
> .pdb - the [Program Data Base](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1%28vs.71%29.aspx) with debug symbols
>
> .vshost.exe.manifest - a kind of [configuration file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375632%28VS.85%29.aspx) containing mostly
>   dependencies on libraries