# why does .Net Core web api create .dll file and pdb file?

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a web API in .net framework 6, when I build a project after changes, it generates a .dll file and .pdb file every time under C:\Users\User\Downloads\Demo.Api\Demo.Api\bin\Debug\net6.0

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202083/whats-a-pdb-file

Comment: Because .pdb is a necessary file for debugging, here is some description from Microsoft : Program database (.pdb) files, also called symbol files, map identifiers and statements in your project's source code to corresponding identifiers and instructions in compiled apps. These mapping files link the debugger to your source code, which enables debugging

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a PDB file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202083/whats-a-pdb-file)

Comment: No, my question is whether the .pdb and .dll are created again and again or a single time.

Comment: every time you make a change and build the project , dll and pdb file will be generated.

Comment: @Anil Thakur, When you change your code or rebuild the project, `pdb` and `dll` file will update.

Comment: A .dll and (optionally) .pdb are the expected results of a build action, so of course after a build they are recreated. Especially after changes to the code

Comment: thanks for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Summary from MS Docs:

> **Why create a .pdb file**
>
> Program database (.pdb) files, also called symbol files, map
> identifiers and statements in your project's source code to
> corresponding identifiers and instructions in compiled apps. These
> mapping files link the debugger to your source code, which enables
> debugging.

More details you can refer to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022),[.NET's Portable PDB format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/symbols)

Comment: So this basically means that I don`t need the .pdb file when I want to implement the .dll somewhere else right?